# Multi-core shared variable visibility, memory model and sequential consistency ordering

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, cpu-cache

Let's assume we have 2 threads that are running in parallel on 2 separate CPUs.

There is a flag that is atomically written and read and a shared variable, both accessed on both threads.

Thread 1 writes the shared variable only once and after that atomically sets the common flag that signals "everything was initialized".
Pseudo code, C-like:

```
uint64 shared = some_value;
atomic_seq_cst_store(init_flag, 1);
...
```

Thread 2 never writes the shared variable, but it reads it, after atomically reading the common flag and "seeing" it was set.
Pseudo code:

```
while (atomic_seq_cst_load(init_flag) != 1) {}
uint64 local_value_of_shared = shared;
...
```

The real situation uses a lot more shared variables (written only once from the init thread) and one single init_flag.

There is one single initializing thread that sets the init_flag to 1 after it's done setting things up and more worker threads that follow the pattern of thread 2 above - they wait for the init_flag to be visible and then they consider all the other shared variables to have been initialized and their up-to-date values visible in the local CPU cache.

Yes, this is yet another cache coherency question :)

The shared variables and the flag are never anything more then 64bit variables.

I'd like to know if this is a safe pattern on a modern multi-core X86 and ARMv8 (and up) CPU.

Compiler is gcc and architecture 64bit only.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I'd consider a pthread barrier instead.

Comment: This is safe, but inefficient. You don't need sequentially consistent loads and stores, only acquire and release. Also, you can use higher-level constructs (that probably compile to the same processor instructions), like `once_flag` in c, or magically thread-safe `static` or `call_once()` or `shared_future` in c++. In c# you'd probably just use `Lazy<T>` and be done.

Comment: @EOF Yes, I'm actually using release in the starting thread and acquire in the workers, for the init_flag. I just formulated the question like that to make it simpler. I'm now wondering if gcc for ARM generates any kind of DMB or DSB instructions for this kind of code...

Comment: It certainly *does* [emit](https://godbolt.org/z/CbKr3J) memory barriers, for both `seq_cst` *and* `acquire/release`, but `seq_cst` needs *more* (until armv8, where dedicated load-acquire/store-release instructions were added).